# Change Line Width of Plot of Fit in Matlab

Tags: plot, matlab, matlab-figure

I'd like to change the width of my fit plot along the lines of:

```
plot(fit, 'LineWidth', WidthSpec)
```

Unfortunately, when I try plotting the data and fit simultaneously like:

```
plot(fit, 'LineWidth', WidthSpec, XData, YData)
```

I get an error message saying

```
??? Error using ==> cfit.plot at 52
EXCLUDEDATA has greater length than XDATA.
```

Plotting both without specification of the width like

```
plot(fit, XData, YData)
```

works just fine.

Comment: have you tried `plot(fit, XData, YData, 'LineWidth', WidthSpec);`?

Comment: this is the function in question: [cfit.plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/plot.html)

Comment: then it should actually work:
plot(cfit,FitLineSpec,x,y,DataLineSpec)

Comment: [LineSpec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) is a string that can only specify color, marker, and line style. For example: `'-.ro'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to store the returned handle and adjust the width using that:

```
h = plot(fit, ...);
set(h, 'LineWidth',2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used:

h = plot(f);
set(h, 'LineWidth',2)

Comment: Consider extending your answer adding information relevant for future readers.